# Postgres check if any of array values is in a list

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I check if any of an array values in a single row is in my list?
Here is my table. Let's call it ABC

```
        id        |   page_id   |                                  values                                   
------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1376092679147519 |     xyz     | {6004036173148,6003373173651,6003050657850}
 1375487155874738 |     xyz     | {6003301698460,6003232518610}
 1497527026945449 |     xyz     | {6003654559478,6003197656807}
 1375388575884596 |     xyz     | {6003512053894,6003450241842,6003051414416}
 1319144441504401 |     xyz     | {6004001256506,6003514818642,6003400993421}
```

My aim is to select those rows, where one of the values appears in the given list ('6004036173148', '6003197656807').

```
SELECT id, page_id, values from ABC WHERE -SOME CLAUSE- IN ('6004036173148', '6003197656807');

        id        |   page_id   |                                  values                                   
------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1376092679147519 |     xyz     | {6004036173148,6003373173651,6003050657850}
 1497527026945449 |     xyz     | {6003654559478,6003197656807}
```

Here is the structure of my PosgreSQL table

```
                             Table "public.ABC"
       Column       |           Type           |       Modifiers        
--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------
 id                 | character varying        | not null
 page_id            | character varying        | not null
 values             | character varying[]      | 
Indexes:
    "ABC_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Side note: try to not use reserved words like `values` as column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understood, you need this:

```
select * from t
where "values" && '{6004036173148,6003197656807}'::character varying[]
```

**EDIT**

If you need extract certain values, then you can use `unnest` function

Note, that if same array contains more than 1 value from searched list, then row will be repeated. Look this example output with `id=2` and you can see, about what I'm talking:

```
with t(id, values) as(
    select 1, '{6004036173147,6003373173651,6003050657840}'::character varying[]
    union all
    select 2, '{6004036173148,6003373173652,6003050657850}'::character varying[]
    union all
    select 3, '{6004036173149,6003373173653,6003050657860}'::character varying[]
)


select tt.* from  
(select t.*, unnest(values) unn from t) tt
inner join (select unnest('{6003373173651,6004036173148,6003373173652}'::character varying[]) v  ) lst
on tt.unn = lst.v
```

Comment: just out of curiosity how would you do this in tsql?

Comment: SQL Server have array types at all?

Comment: I don't Think so.

Comment: If so, how would we work with array  in tsql? or I missed your question?

Comment: I guess you could fake it: CREATE TABLE   #temp     ( id  VARCHAR(20),   page_id   VARCHAR(10),   rValues   VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
 ('1376092679147519' ,'xyz','{6004036173148,6003373173651,6003050657850}'),
 ('1375487155874738' ,'xyz','{6003301698460,6003232518610}'    ),
 ('1497527026945449' ,'xyz','{6003654559478,6003197656807}'    ),
 ('1375388575884596' ,'xyz','{6003512053894,6003450241842,6003051414416}'),
 ('1319144441504401' ,'xyz','{6004001256506,6003514818642,6003400993421}')

 SELECT *  FROM #temp WHERE PATINDEX('%6003514818642%', rValues) > 0

Comment: @Godric - Glad to help

Comment: @KamranFarzami - This is typical `VARCHAR` type right? may be simply `LIKE` operator does similar job

Comment: @OtoShavadze do you know maybe how to extract ONLY those `values` that appear in a list ?